# Kitchen Sink P Trap Installation Advice

Tags: plumbing

My question is where to install a P trap on this configuration (Disposal is directly over the drain pipe). We are on conventional foundation, so is installing P trap under the house an option? We went from a double sink to a single deeper sink and there was only 6 inches of clearance so I took a chance with no P trap....bad idea. Sewer gas now coming in regularly.  Any help with details and illustrations from a plumber would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Max

[image: Here is the current config.]

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to put a trap in there somewhere.  If there's enough space in the cabinet, you could do something similar to this...

[image]
<sup>*NOTE::* All horizontal pipe sloped at 1/4" per foot.*</sup>

If not, and you have access to the plumbing below. You could reroute the plumbing, so the it comes up the back wall instead.

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be allowed by code for new plumbing, you can use an S Trap.  You will have to rebuild things to get things aligned correctly, but an S trap is exactly what you need if you are trying to get this going quickly and in a pinch.   Just make sure the drain is vented after the trap in the crawlspace so the draining water does not siphon the water out of the trap.

Comment: AFAIK s-traps aren't allowed (code) because they have the potential to siphon the water out of the trap - leaving you in the same position you were in with no trap at all.

Comment: An S trap is many times better than what they have now; and what is actually allowed is up to the code official.  Sometimes they allow them.  Granted if there is room to get a p trap into place, they would force a P trap.  Also, not all s traps siphon the the water, typically its s-traps with no vent.  I modified my answer to reflect this.